# Send email through a contact form wordpress on Amazon ec2 (windows) issue

Tags: php, wordpress, email, amazon-ec2

Do we really need the Amazon SES service to send email through amazon ec2. I am unable to send emails through Wordpress hosted on Amazon ec2(windows).

1. Have added port 25 in the security group.
2. i am using Contact form 7 of wordpress
3. I am running wordpress on amazon ec2 windows instance.

Please help do i need to do anything else?

I am new to Amazon ec2

Comment: Check out http://www.mailgun.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any SMTP server ready then you can simply use default php `mail()` to send mail from your wordpress website.

1. Install [contact 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for wordpress, to create forms.
2. Install [Wp-Mail-SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin to setup mailer config
3. Add this line in your wp-config file: `define('RELOCATE',1);`
4. Install sendmail package in ubuntu machine using: `sudo apt-get install sendmail`

This works for me for **EC2 server of AWS** and also resolved **could not instantiate mail function** error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of smtp server, probably not one hosted on the instance.

Unlike linux, windows generally doesn't come with an smtp mail server or mail relay pre-installed. You can set up your own, but sending mail directly from an ec2 instance can be problematic with spam filters.

Your best bet is to relay email via SES or another mail service.